# What version of Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, gui

I have Raspberry Pi 2, and I'm attempting to install the [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) GUI, following the guide from:

http://wiki.octave.org/Rasperry_Pi

[image]

I'm using Raspberry Pi version:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install lsb-release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  lsb
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lsb-release
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 105 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main lsb-release all 4.1+Debian8+rpi1+deb7u1 [26.8 kB]
Fetched 26.8 kB in 2s (11.9 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package lsb-release.
(Reading database ... 76938 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking lsb-release (from .../lsb-release_4.1+Debian8+rpi1+deb7u1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up lsb-release (4.1+Debian8+rpi1+deb7u1) ...
```

What do I install for the Raspberry Pi GUI?

Is there a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)-like viewer for Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian “wheezy” Release Information

Debian 7.8 was released January 10th, 2015. Debian 7.0 was initially released on May 4th, 2013. 
That seems to be what you need from the Octave wiki.  However to check the version:

cat /etc/issue

To check the update point release:

cat /etc/debian_version

For the Pi GUI type:

startx

My favorite VNC is realVNC:

https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/raspberrypi/

This works transparently with the Pi, Mac & Windows !